# Setting up Android DE in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, dot42

I'm working on an alien environment where most things I search in Google about Android Development does not apply immediately, there's a work around I must do first before I get it to work.

I use [dot42](http://www.dot42.com) (*I don't know what to call it*) integrated in `VS` to be able to develop an app in `Android` using `C#`. Now in this kind of environment, I think the documentation and reference online are lacking (or just hard for me to look up for) so a newbie like me find it difficult to work to.

### Questions:

1. How can I setup the **file system** / **folders** /
   **configuration** structure so I can work like I'm developing in `Eclipse` with `Java`? For example: In `Eclipse`, there's a default **res**
   folder?
2. If I'm going to do a manual `XML` setup, like adding a `drawables`,
   where should I put it? What should be the format?
3. How can I setup the search path for each resources so I can find it easily with only a few `string path`?
4. What kind of tree folder do you recommend? For example:

---

```
[-]apps
 ' 
 ' [-]res
 '  '
 '  ' [-]drawables
 '  '  ' 
 '  '  ' -bg1.png
 '  '  ' -bg2.png
 '  ' [-]layouts
 '  '  '
 '  '  ' -style2
 '  '  ' -mainactivitylayout.xml
 ' [-]sources
 '  '  
 '  ' -constants.cs
 '  ' -mainactivity.cs
[-]widgets
 ' 
 ' [-]res
 '  '
 '  ' [+]drawables
 '  ' [+]layouts
 ' [+]sources
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say ive ever used Dot42, infact ive never heard of it which is odd because I have  been looking into these kinds of frameworks lately.

However after a very simple search I found documentation detailing exactly what you want:

http://docs.dot42.com/resources

Does the documenation not tell you what you need to know?

As it is still in it's infancy I would say that it may be worth starting a dialog with the developers to see if you can ask them these kinds of questions too.

Comment: Yeah but the documentation assumes that the developer have all the basic knowledge to do those. Perhaps the link somewhat answers the question `#4`.

Answer (score 0):

dot42 uses the Build Action of a project item instead of its path like Eclipse does:

[image]

You are free to use the folder structure that you prefer but the structure itself won't imply the meaning of a resource file. dot42 does allow you to import an existing res folder after which it sets the Build Actions accordingly:

[image]

Comment: Does the path locating for each one of the resources I will use wouldn't mess up even if the folder structure is too deep? Does the dot42 automatically do this kind of task?

Comment: Are you referring to importing an existing res folder? If so, yes dot42 *should* do this automatically.